# Is there any way to implement zstd compression in fluentd s3 plugin?

Tags: ruby, logging, fluentd

We have the requirement to compress and send files to S3 with `zstd` compression. I am trying to implement `zstandard` compression plugin with `fluentd` s3 plugin so that the data that is sent to s3 using `fluentd` agent is stored in `zstd` format and not the default gzip. Not able to find any solution yet. Any help is appreciated.

Installed td-agent fluentd in a Linux system and installed `zstd-ruby` and `ztsd` gems. Created the `s3_compressor_zstd.rb` algo and copied it to `/opt/x.x.x.x/fluent-plugin-s3-1.7.2/lib/fluent/plugin` directory. While starting the fluentd agent I am getting the below error:

[image: Logs of td-agent service]

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
td-agent version: 4.4.2
fluentd version: 1.15.3
zstd version: 1.1.2.1
zstd-ruby version: 1.5.2.3
```

`s3_compressor_zstd.rb` file:

```rb
require "zstd"
module Fluent::Plugin
  class S3Output
    class ZstdCompressor < Compressor
      S3Output.register_compressor('zstd', self)
      def initialize(options = {})
        begin
          require "zstd"
        rescue LoadError
          raise Fluent::ConfigError, "Install zstd-ruby gem before using zstd compressor"
        end
      end
      def ext
        ".zst"
      end
      def compress(data)
        compressed_data = ''
        Zstd::Writer.open(StringIO.new(compressed_data)) do |compressed_stream|
          compressed_stream.write(data)
        end
        compressed_data
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Use your (de)compression algorithm](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3/blob/master/docs/howto.md#use-your-decompression-algorithm), `compress` takes two arguments:

```rb
      # chunk is buffer chunk. tmp is destination file for upload
      def compress(chunk, tmp)
        # call command or something
      end
```

You need to update your implementation accordingly.

Check the implementation of the **existing supported compressors** here:

- https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3/tree/master/lib/fluent/plugin

Here's a thread that discusses **snappy compressor** (might be helpful):

- https://groups.google.com/g/fluentd/c/4KME4WB-np8

---

**UPDATE**

Using [zstd](https://github.com/DatekWireless/zstd) gem, the implementation of the compressor may look like this (**not tested**):

```rb
require 'zstd'

module Fluent::Plugin
  class S3Output
    class LZMA2Compressor < Compressor
      S3Output.register_compressor('zstd', self)

      def initialize(options = {})
        begin
          require 'zstd'
        rescue LoadError
          raise Fluent::ConfigError, 'zstd gem not installed, run: gem install zstd'
        end
      end

      def ext
        'zst'.freeze
      end

      def compress(chunk, tmp)
        s = StringIO.new
        chunk.write_to(s)
        tmp.write(Zstd.new.compress(s.string))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I modified the .rb file and getting a new error.

Comment: s3_compressor_zstd.rb file:
require "zstd"
module Fluent::Plugin
  class S3Output
    class ZstdCompressor < Compressor
      S3Output.register_compressor('zstd', self)
      def initialize(options = {})
        begin
          require "zstd"
        rescue LoadError
          raise Fluent::ConfigError, "Install zstd-ruby gem before using zstd compressor"
        end
      end
      def ext
        ".zst"
      end
      def compress(chunk, tmp)
        w = Zstd::Writer.new(tmp)
        chunk.write_to(w)
        w.close
      end
    end
  end
end

Comment: ERROR MSG:
2023-01-31 07:31:48 +0000 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_times=1 next_retry_time=2023-01-31 07:31:51 +0000 chunk="5f389ca69d87ec995e5a5ec007dab4c0" error_class=NameError error="uninitialized constant Zstd::Writer"

Comment: The Updated one works fine the use case. Thanks @Azeem

Comment: @AkashSaini: Good to hear that. You're welcome! Thanks for letting me know!